# make 301 redirect from old asp page to wordpress php

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can anyone help me make a 301 redirect from an asp page: http://www.maribowl.dk/bowling.asp?Page=Caf%E9+Menu to my new wordpress site: http://www.maribowl.dk/cafemenu/

can this be done in an .htaccess file on the wordpress site or where should I paste it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page=St\%E6vne [NC]
RewriteRule ^Tournaments\.asp$ http://www.maribowl.dk/julestaevne-2013/? [B,R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have the yoast wordpress plugin and in the .htaccess, I already have the following code: 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress 
- how do I make that work together with what you wrote? If I change it a bit it gives me 404, I tried to paste in your code in the wordpress tages/modules
@anubhava

Comment: Insert this rule just below RewriteBase line.

Comment: Wrong info - old link is this
http://maribowl.dk/Tournaments.asp?Page=St%E6vne
and I need to redirect to: http://www.maribowl.dk/julestaevne-2013/
old page does not have www. New page should redirect to www version, this is what I tried:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page=St\%E6\+vne$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^tournaments\.asp$ /julestaevne-2013/? [B,R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress 
@anubhava

Comment: As per your question you had `www` in both old and new URLs. Any reason of changing the question?

Comment: the old link was wrong and it needs to go to another page on the new site. I tried to make it according to your pattern but it just says that it can't find the page. ohh yes the new site should have: http://www.maribowl.dk/julestaevne-2013

Comment: okay stackoverflow removes www in front when I write out the url in here

Comment: ok try the updated code now.