# Redirect old .asp pages to Wordpress php pages .htaccess

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, redirect

I just replaced an ASP website with a Wordpress website and I need to to the 301 redirects for the old pages.

I've been trying to understand how to do it from Asp to Wordpress pages.

For example:

This is my ASP link:

http://www.edtech.ie/details.asp?ptid=20041&ID=15393

And this is the link where I'd like to redirect the ASP link:

http://www.edtech.ie/product/numbershark5/

I've tried to look for some answers but I could find any that worked.

I tried

```
Redirect 301 /details.asp?ptid=20041&ID=15393 http://www.edtech.ie/product/numbershark5/
```

And obviously didn't work.

I tried this solution but maybe I set it up in the wrong way and didn't work:

[make 301 redirect from old asp page to wordpress php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033855/make-301-redirect-from-old-asp-page-to-wordpress-php)

Any quick advice on how to do this redirect through .htaccess?

Comment: Why is it obvious your redirect would not work- That is one method to use with an .htaccess file? You can do a lot more with RewriteRule (from ModRewrite) though, so perhaps you should look at that.

Comment: Hi, it seems that Redirect 301 /details.asp?ptid=20041&ID=15393 http://www.edtech.ie/product/numbershark5/  doesn't work from ASP to PHP. I just found a solution by using RewriteCond and RewriteRule, it took me a while to get how to place the data but now it's working fine, I'll post the answer in a while, cheers!